# How to customize Telerik Header Context Menu?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, aspx-user-control

I want to customize the [Telerik Header Context Menu](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/columns-rows/columns/context-menu/defaultcs.aspx) by adding additional button to it and I want to change labels of existing buttons. How can I do it? I know that I can [set custom CSS class](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/columns/header-context-menu#set-custom-cssclass-to-the-headercontextmenu), but this is not I'm looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnPreRenderComplete(ByVal e As EventArgs)Dim menu As RadContextMenu = RadGrid1.HeaderContextMenu
    Dim item As New RadMenuItem()
    item.Text = "Format"
    item.Attributes("ColumnName") = String.Empty
    item.Attributes("TableID") = String.Empty
    BuildColumnsMenu(item, RadGrid1.MasterTableView)
    menu.Items.Add(item)
    MyBase.OnPreRenderComplete(e)End Sub
```